# Webservice Applicationpool

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, ssis

I have two diffrent web services(running on local machine) and pointing to one application pool(1.Can I do that?Is it any performance concern?).I have not much knowledge about how the applicationpool will works. 
 the other .Net application is using two webservices,but frequently one  webservice is not responding which internally calling by ssis package with in the .Net application.
what might be the reason and how to make sure it responds all the time, is there any better way to improve the performance?

if am missing or any further information, Comments Welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple web applications using to the same application pool.

Is it a performance concern?  If it is really high traffic or is faulty code, then perhaps.

Application pools allow pushing sites to different processes, reducing the risk of each affecting the other.  If one app pool contains an application/web application that has a memory leak, the leak will only affect that particular process, at least directly.  Each process can be recycled either by time or system parameters, which mitigates risks of having something in a bad state.

Performance?  Another benefit to app pools is the ability to have multiple instances running simultaneously (a similar thing when putting each app in its own pool).  The benefit of this is that more request can be handled at a time.  The down-side is that you cannot use in-process session state and your application state will be duplicated for each instance of the process.  You would need to consider how much 'stuff' you keep in session and how your caching scheme would be effected, but, it has potential for giving a web application more scalability.

You mention call SSIS... I am assuming that is a long-running service, so you would probably want to push the call to that process to some sort of queue that can process outside of the web service request.  MSMQ might work for you.  If using a queue as such, you would initiate the running of the code, then have a way of checking on the status of the call to see if it is done.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Greg Ogle but one more point I think is worth mentioning. Splitting the applications into multiple app pools will also give you an added benefit when it comes to troubleshooting if there are any issues. If you have the various applications split out, you can tell specifically what app pool is related to what w3wp.exe process in the time of need. Like say when that w3wp.exe process is taking 98% of your cpu.